# Facebook invite friends dialog height issue

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, fbjs

We have integrated Facebook Connect to our website, including the invite friends function.

The funny thing is, some users are able to see the full dialog and some users are only able to see the dialog in the picture shown below.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution is to display invite dialog as a pop-up instead.

```
FB.ui({
    method : 'apprequests',
    message: 'Your message',
    display: 'popup'
},
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug reported [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194725433940802).

Here is the response, written on November 18 at 9:12pm:
"We already have a fix for this issue and it will be pushed soon."

Answer (score 1):

This is a facebook bug. Report to them.